# Splitting Flask code into different files

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, routes

Below is the python flask code.

All I want to do is split the code into different files as in
all the routes in views.py, configure db in db.py and use them in app.py or where ever required.

Also I want to use db in some of the routes so how do I call it in views.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, make_response, jsonify
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import yaml


app = Flask(__name__)

# middleware
cors = CORS(app)


# configure db
db = yaml.safe_load(open('db.yaml'))
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = db['mysql_host']
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = db['mysql_user']
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = db['mysql_password']
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = db['mysql_db']

mysql = MySQL(app)

# routes

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def index():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    sql_select_query_check = """UPDATE users SET Password = %s, Password_Status = %s WHERE ID = %s"""
    cur.execute(sql_select_query_check, (hashcode, 1, userid[0]))
    mysql.connection.commit()  
    return jsonify({"message": "password updated"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Comment: what did you try? Did you get error message? always put full errormessag (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as tex (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: theres no error and nothing. I just want to split this code into multiple files as in separate routes file, db, and main file. @furas

Comment: did you try to split? First try, and ask question when it will gives errors.

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `flask` documentation you can see [Larger Applications](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/) which shows how to split code. And it mentions that main problem can be circular import - `main` imports `views` which has to import `main` to get `app`. The same problem is with `db.py` which would need to import `main` to get `app`

---

I move `app` to separated file `application.py` to skip circular import

[image]

I don't run code and maybe it would need to import `mysql` to `views.py`

But maybe it should be done with `Blueprint()` or with functions which will be imported to `main.py` and run with argument `app`.

---

**application.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

**db.py**

```
from application import app
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import yaml

db = yaml.safe_load(open('db.yaml'))
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = db['mysql_host']
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = db['mysql_user']
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = db['mysql_password']
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = db['mysql_db']

mysql = MySQL(app)
```

**views.py**

```
from application import app

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def index():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    sql_select_query_check = """UPDATE users SET Password = %s, Password_Status = %s WHERE ID = %s"""
    cur.execute(sql_select_query_check, (hashcode, 1, userid[0]))
    mysql.connection.commit()  
    return jsonify({"message": "password updated"})
```

**main.py**

```
from application import app

from flask import render_template, request, redirect, make_response, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

from views import *

# middleware
cors = CORS(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version with code in functions `init()` and without `application.py` - but I didn't test if it will works. But it starts looking like code with `Blueprint`

**db.py**

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import yaml

def init(app):
    db = yaml.safe_load(open('db.yaml'))
    app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = db['mysql_host']
    app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = db['mysql_user']
    app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = db['mysql_password']
    app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = db['mysql_db']

    return MySQL(app)
```

**views.py**

```
def init(app, mysql):

    @app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
    def index():
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        sql_select_query_check = """UPDATE users SET Password = %s, Password_Status = %s WHERE ID = %s"""
        cur.execute(sql_select_query_check, (hashcode, 1, userid[0]))
        mysql.connection.commit()  
        return jsonify({"message": "password updated"})
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, make_response, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import db
import views

app = Flask(__name__)

# middleware
cors = CORS(app)
myslq = db.init(app)
views.init(app, mysql)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

---

But I would rather keep `views` with `app = Flask(__name__)` in one file.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I did the same keeping views and app in the same file, but I've been told to split the code